# Facebook how to send app authorize request to friends?

Tags: android, facebook, request, authorize

I'm building an application that connect with Facebook. When user use my app, I can get their friends list and display it. Now I want add an option that user can send a request to their friend to ask them to authorize my app. Here's my code:

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(MY_APP_ID);
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("to", MY_FRIEND_ID);
params.putString("message", "This is the message text");
facebook.dialog(((Activity) ctx).getParent(), "apprequests",
        params, new DialogListener() {

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("invite", "complete");
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("invite", "e1");
            }

            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("invite", "e2");
            }

            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("invite", "cancel");
            }

        });
```

OK this code works and it sends an app request to my friend. But that request will redirect my friend to the app canvas page set up in facebook app setting. Is there a way to send a request that redirect my friend to the page authorize my app. I think in `facebook.dialog(((Activity) ctx).getParent(), "apprequests",
                    params, new DialogListener() {` I have to replace apprequests with something else. Can anybody help me out with this?

**EDIT:**
Ok don't worry about it. I figured it out. The facebook account receive the request already authorize the app. When I remove that app from app setting, my code will redirect to authorize page.